# Is there a way to start screen recording of a external application from my own Android application

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, screen-recording

Is there a specific android screen recorder application that starts screen recording as soon as it is opened, or is there a workaround to start some of the more popular recorders?

I've already tried creating my own screen recording in my application using MediaProjection, it works, but i need it to start another application.